# Root view controller warning after converting to ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, automatic-ref-counting

I'm converting my opengl game to ARC and am running into this error/warning message with the app launches:

> Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch.

I am not using nib or xib files to create my views or windows.  Everything works fine in non-arc code (and has for a couple of years now).

After the error/warning, the game goes on and runs just fine, but I'd like to know what's causing this as it might cause problems down the road.

My guess is something is not being retained correctly now that it's arc, but I can't figure out what.  Any ideas?  Here is how I am creating my opengl views and the window.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    [window setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [window setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

    glView = [[EAGLView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    [window addSubview:glView];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [glView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startMainGameLoop) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; 

    return YES;
}
```

and...

```
@interface GameAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> 
{
    UIWindow *window;
    EAGLView *glView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The "`Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch.`" messages are popping up for many people not setting the rootViewController property on their application delegate's window property in iOS5 on Xcode 4.2. **(Not ARC dependant)**

[A question on why this message shows up has been posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8548582/927947).

Right now it seems to be a friendly warning. Although the general feeling is that it will become a rule.

It might be worth taking a look at the project template for a "OpenGL Game" in Xcode. That would seem to be the way apple wants all applications structured.

Comment: It might not be ARC dependent, but it only happens on code that has ARC turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use @property and @synthesize for glView.

Answer (score 0):

change to

@synthesize window;

instead of

@synthesize window=_window;